# Windows Performance Recorder - Failed to gather system information (Error Code 0x8007002)

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to perform a boot trace on my computer (because it takes 10 minutes to boot Windows 10 and I'm trying to find the reason why), but after it boots and 2 minutes passes it spits out the following error:

Failed to gather system information for On/Off - Boot Trace
-> Unable to find the specified file
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKUY4.png)

Have no clue what to do

Comment: Are you running the WPT as administrator?

Comment: Are you running the new Windows 10 version of the tool?
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install

Comment: Running as administrator. Installer I used is Windows Software Development Kit - Windows 10.0.17763.132

Comment: Deleted and reinstalled using link above. Same result @HackSlash

Comment: You might find that running Process Monitor as a boot trace might also give you the information you need. I appreciate this is a workaround but worth considering.